# data normalization after dimension reduction for classification

Tags: classification, mathematical-statistics, normalization, dimensionality-reduction, data-preprocessing

The classifier is KNN or RBF-SVM. After doing dimension reduction (e.g., PCA, LDA or KPCA, KLDA), does it need to do normalization before classification?

In `LIBSVM` package, it always needs to first use `svm-scale` to normalize the features using min-max normalization, then takes the normalized features as inputs for `svm-train`.

I'm not sure whether the data normalization would harm the structures of the transformed features by PCA, LDA etc.

Comment: Please see some general recommendations one nomalization/scaling: e.g. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19216/variables-are-often-adjusted-e-g-standardised-before-making-a-model-when-is and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29781/when-conducting-multiple-regression-when-should-you-center-your-predictor-varia

Answer (score 1):

PCA does require normalization as a pre-processing step.

> Normalization is important in PCA since it is a variance maximizing
>   exercise. It projects your original data onto directions which
>   maximize the variance. Source: [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69157/why-do-we-need-to-normalize-data-before-analysis)

**Would a further step of data normalization harm the data?**

No, it would not harm the data. But would it be really necessary?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

mean = [0.0, 20.0]
cov = [[1.0, 0.7], [0.7, 1000]]
values = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 1000)

pca = PCA(n_components=1, whiten=True)
pca.fit(values)

values_ = pca.transform(values)
print np.var(values_)
```

The following exercise returns `1.0`

Why? We are projecting two whitened features onto the first component.
Let's assume that a point in the whitened space is identified by a vector ($a$)
The new vector ($a'$) is the result of the transformation 
$$a' = |a| * \cos(\theta) = a \cdot \hat{b} $$

where we have $|a|$ is the length of $a$; and $\theta$ is the angle between the vector $a$ and the vector we are projecting onto. In this case $b$ equals $e$, the eigenvectors, that maps each row vector onto the principal component.

What is the variance of the whitened feature once projected on the principal component?

$$\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum^n (a_i \cdot e)^2 = e^T \frac{a^Ta}{n} e$$

$e^Te = 1$ by definition (eigenvectors are unit vectors). Note that when we whitened the data, we imposed that means are zero on the feature set.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for this detail answer. This is very helpful! In fact, I've also posted a question with more details in https://www.quora.com/Does-it-need-feature-normalization-after-dimension-reduction-for-classification, and there are some kind answers and discussions there. If convenient, please kindly check it. Thanks!

Comment: Apologies, reading again my own answer I have realized that I made a mistake. Pls check the correction.

Comment: Thank you very much for your revision! It seems the conclusion is similar to this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119913/pca-first-or-normalization-first].