# Does PCA normalize data with respect to standard deviation?

Tags: pca, standard-deviation, normalization

In my textbook it says the data is assumed to be zero-centered. I am not sure what this means. I read it stand for substracting the mean from the individual values, however I would like to know do you divide the values by the standard deviation as well.

For example if one dimension had values 8 10 12 and another 80 100 120, the latter would have much more variation and consequently PCA would assign it a greater weight. My question is whether we divide the data by standard deviation as well.

Answer (score 3):

You're right, each attribute should always be normalised before PCA occurs. Check out this answer: [Why do we need to normalize data before principal component analysis (PCA)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69157/why-do-we-need-to-normalize-data-before-principal-component-analysis-pca)